# Load environment variable in boot file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am facing issue while loading envrionment variable in boot.rb. I tried with 2 gems dotenv & dotenv-rails but none of them worked for me. Other places I am able to use environment variable but not in boot.rb. Anyone have any clue on this one

```
if ["development"].include?(ENV['RAILS_ENV'])
   require 'bootsnap/setup'
   
   Bootsnap.setup(
    cache_dir:            'tmp/cache',          # Path to your cache
    development_mode:     'development', # Current working environment, e.g. RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, etc
    load_path_cache:      true,                 # Optimize the LOAD_PATH with a cache
    autoload_paths_cache: true,                 # Optimize ActiveSupport autoloads with cache
    compile_cache_iseq:   true,                 # Compile Ruby code into ISeq cache, breaks coverage reporting.
    compile_cache_yaml:   true                  # Compile YAML into a cache
  )
end
```

Comment: You did not say what's the content of `RAILS_ENV`, but since your array has only one element (`"development"`), you could rewrite your condition to `if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development"`. It's the same as your current code, but easier to understand.

Comment: RAILS_ENV=development is set in the .env file

Comment: Maybe, but to which value? Also, are you sure that the `.env` file has been processed, when this code is executed? I suggest to print out this value for debugging.

Comment: I try to debug the value of ENV['RAILS_ENV'] it is giving nil. But when I check in rails console or anywhere in the application it is giving me the correct value. What I suspect is at the time of boot .env file doesn't load

Comment: I have voted to close the question then.

Comment: @user1934428 Why have you voted to close the question?

Comment: AniketTiwari : Because the question does not have much meaning anymore, if RAILS_ENV is not defined. You maybe have now a new question, _why is .env not processed_, but this is a different question than the current one, and IMO not even one which goes well with Stackoverflow.

Comment: @user1934428 EN['RAILS_ENV']  IS NOT accessible only in boot.rb file rest places I am able ot access it. And in my question I have clearly stated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DotEnv will only load your `.env` file into env once the Gem has been loaded.

In Rails this is done by the line `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in `config/application.rb`. If you need to access the env vars before that you need to manually call `Dotenv::Railtie.load`:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
Dotenv::Railtie.load
```

Or at least thats [what the readme would lead you to belive](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#note-on-load-order). Instead of the Railtie I guess you could use the plain ruby approach:

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

But there are tons options to set ENV vars from a file such as [direnv](https://direnv.net/) which is not a Ruby gem and hooks into your shell itself.

Comment: Thanks it didn't work like that but it gave me the hint. When I added Dotenv::Railtie.load in application.rb it was private method `load' called for Dotenv::Railtie:Class. Then I tried again the same line in boot.rb still it didn't work. Later what I tried with these two lines in boot.rb and it worked require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load

Comment: I guess [the docs](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#note-on-load-order) are broken then. I haven't used dotenv in years. `direnv` does the job and avoids cluttering your gemfile with what is actually machine specific tooling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use - depending on your needs - a `load` or `require` to explicitly process your `.env` file, before testing the environment variable.